# How can I loop through a List<T> and grab each item?

Tags: c#, for-loop, collections

How can I loop through a List and grab each item?

I want the output to look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("amount is {0}, and type is {1}", myMoney.amount, myMoney.type);
```

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Money> myMoney = new List<Money> 
    {
        new Money{amount = 10, type = "US"},
        new Money{amount = 20, type = "US"}
    };
}

class Money
{
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 356, accepted):

`foreach`:

```
foreach (var money in myMoney) {
    Console.WriteLine("Amount is {0} and type is {1}", money.amount, money.type);
}
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

Alternatively, because it is a `List<T>`.. which implements an indexer method `[]`, you can use a normal `for` loop as well.. although its less readble (IMO):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myMoney.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Amount is {0} and type is {1}", myMoney[i].amount, myMoney[i].type);
}
```

Comment: @awudoin What? No it doesn't.. it creates a reference on the stack.. other than that, it doesn't. A `foreach` doesn't clone the objects..

Comment: I should clarify: It also creates an `Enumerator`.. which is a `struct`.. which is also on the stack. So I still don't quite get what you were getting at with your comment.

Comment: You're right....it is just an `Enumerator` and not a copy of the object. But the fact remains, depending on what you're doing there is more overhead with a `foreach` loop vs. a `for` loop. I just ran a quick test with your code with 100,000 entries in the `List` and the `foreach` loop took twice as long (actually 1.9 times as long). This isn't necessarily true in all situations, but in many. It depends on the size of the List, how many operations you do within the loop, etc.... This was what I was getting at.

Answer (score 43):

Just for completeness, there is also the LINQ/Lambda way:

```
myMoney.ForEach((theMoney) => Console.WriteLine("amount is {0}, and type is {1}", theMoney.amount, theMoney.type));
```

Comment: This is much cleaner

Comment: @jet_choong That is a personal opinion. Mine is that it is not clearer than either *foreach* or *for*.

Comment: Depends on the length of the code inside of it, I guess...

Comment: @acarlon Why IList does not accept ForEach?

Answer (score 25):

Just like any other collection.  With the addition of the `List<T>.ForEach` method.

```
foreach (var item in myMoney)
    Console.WriteLine("amount is {0}, and type is {1}", item.amount, item.type);

for (int i = 0; i < myMoney.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("amount is {0}, and type is {1}", myMoney[i].amount, myMoney[i].type);

myMoney.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine("amount is {0}, and type is {1}", item.amount, item.type));
```

Comment: Another word of warning, if you have a big list, (by big I mean over 100,000 items) myMoney.Count start to take a while as it has to traverse the list to perform the Count, and in the for examples above the myMoney.Count is counted every time around the loop. So using int myMoneyC=myMoney.Count; for(int i=0;i < myMoneyC; i++)  will make this loop many times faster.

Comment: @SuperGSJ Have you tested this? I would expect that it is optimized when you compile for release.

Answer (score 16):

This is how I would write using more `functional way`. Here is the code:

```
new List<Money>()
{
     new Money() { Amount = 10, Type = "US"},
     new Money() { Amount = 20, Type = "US"}
}
.ForEach(money =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"amount is {money.Amount}, and type is {money.Type}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very short way to achieve this task. You have also used the new and compact syntax of writeLine that was introduced in VS 2017/ .NET 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

The low level `iterator` manipulate code:

```
List<Money> myMoney = new List<Money>
{
    new Money{amount = 10, type = "US"},
    new Money{amount = 20, type = "US"}
};
using (var enumerator = myMoney.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var element = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(element.amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that if the List is changed, you will get "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." with this method.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Not just this method, but any method which *enumerates* the list (e.g. foreach), and the list changes, will throw the same exception. A **for** loop does not *enumerate* the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the while loop

```
   int ctr = 0;
   while (ctr <= myMoney.Count - 1)
   {
       var data = myMoney[ctr];
       Console.WriteLine($"{data.amount} - {data.type}");
       ctr++;
   }
```