# How to add "String[] or List<String>" as ONE cell entry in a DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable containing cells with lines > 1.
(FYI: new to C#, doesn't know anything about OOPS...Please be kind)
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
namespace Excelapp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("LOCarray",typeof(String[]));
        table.Columns.Add("LOCstring", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("LOClist", typeof(List<String>));


        String[] LOCarray = new String[2] {"Line1","Line2" };
        String LOCstring = "Line1\n\rLine2";
        List<String> LOClist = new List<String>();
        LOClist.Add("Line1");
        LOClist.Add("Line2");

        table.Rows.Add(LOCarray, LOCstring, LOClist);

        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

[DataSet Visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a396S.png)
[image]

As you can see, This is not what I want. Even when I am writing as String it is not showing \n character.

Please help me.

Comment: You showed what you *don't* want, but what *do* you want it to look like?

Comment: A `DataTable` is a structure, not a display component, so your `\n` won't be rendered. When you view the data in the visualiser, it removes escape characters. If you read that line out and display it in a text component or the console, you will see the new line.

Comment: there should be multiple lines in one cell of row

Comment: you add your abject to Rows. you need to add your object properties to rows not the object. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863187/how-can-i-loop-through-a-listt-and-grab-each-item)

Comment: You can't put multiple values in a Datatable cell. A list of strings doesn't have newlines either. You are probably confusing the data structure with the way it's displayed in a grid.

Comment: I see, So whats the way around? I want to store multiples lines in one cell and then write whole matrix to an excel sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] arr = { "one", "two", "three" };

string arrayValuesWithNewLineSep = string.Join("\n", arr));
```

Comment: He mentions something about it not showing "\n" characters, I'm not convinced that this is the answer he is looking for.

Comment: Still this is the only sensible answer. The OP confuses datatables with grids.

Comment: Is it possible he just wants the textboxes in the grids to be multi-line; to break on the newline character, and is under the mistaken impression that putting the values in arrays should do that?

Comment: I want to write this datatable to excel later. Each cell of excel will have multiple lines

Comment: Excel doesn't support "arrays" as cell values either, only strings and numbers.  Convert the array (or list) to a string with newlines as separators.`Join` is the most effective way to do that.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Got it. Thank you very much!!! You have no idea how much time I have wasted around this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you prefer Linq is to use the `Aggregate` function.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = new List<string>() { "This", "is", "a", "sentence", "."};

var sentence = collection.Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b);
```

Or in your case, it'd be

```
var myValue = locList.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "\n\r" + b);
```