# C# how to loop json2csharp generated classes lists

Tags: c#, json, loops, arraylist

After using `http://json2csharp.com/` I got this stucture and I am trying to loop through all Books, however I don't know how and I guess there is a better way then to getting every Book list by hand like this `BookStores[0].Prism.Books`

In short I want to loop through every `List<Book>`

```
    public class Book
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int pages { get; set; }
        public double rating { get; set; }
        public bool available { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prism
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paragraphia
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }


    public class BookStore
    {
        public Prism Prism { get; set; }
        public Paragraphia Paragraphia { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<BookStore> BookStores { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Ideally your question should be how to use loops with list in C# ?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863187/how-can-i-loop-through-a-listt-and-grab-each-item

Comment: No, look class BookStore has members Prism and Paragraphia  and those members have their members which are Lists. How do I loop them without directly accessing each one with a dot

Answer (score 0):

What about the following implementation.

```
public class Book
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public bool available { get; set; }
}

public enum BookCategory
{
    Prism,
    Paragraphia
}

public class BookStore
{
    public Dictionary<BookCategory, List<Book>> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var bookStore = new BookStore();
bookStore.Books = new Dictionary<BookCategory, List<Book>>();

var paragrapiaBooks = new List<Book>();
paragrapiaBooks.Add(new Book{name = "Paragrapia book 1"});
paragrapiaBooks.Add(new Book{name = "Paragrapia book 2"});
bookStore.Books[BookCategory.Paragraphia] = paragrapiaBooks;

var prismBooks = new List<Book>();
prismBooks.Add(new Book{name = "Prism book 1"});
prismBooks.Add(new Book{name = "Prism book 2"});
bookStore.Books[BookCategory.Prism] = prismBooks;

foreach (var bookCategory in bookStore.Books)
{
    foreach (var book in bookCategory.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(book.name);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This way your implementation is also more flexible, you don't have to add a new property when you need a new book category, you just have to add a new `Enum` value. Instead of an `Enum` you can also use a `String` for example.

======================================================================

But I think the following solution is better, by adding property `category` to the `Book` class, because it is in fact a property of the book and not of the collection of books. A science fiction novel will still be science fiction even when it is placed on a bookshelf full of cookbooks.

```
public class Book
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public bool available { get; set; }
}

public class BookStore
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var bookStore = new BookStore();
bookStore.Books = new List<Book>();
bookStore.Books.Add(new Book { name = "Paragrapia book 1", category = "Paragrapia" });
bookStore.Books.Add(new Book { name = "Paragrapia book 2", category = "Paragrapia" });
bookStore.Books.Add(new Book { name = "Prism book 1", category = "Prism" });
bookStore.Books.Add(new Book { name = "Prism book 2", category = "Prism" });

Console.WriteLine("ONLY PRISM BOOKS:");
foreach (var book in bookStore.Books.Where(b => b.category == "Prism"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(book.name);
}

Console.WriteLine("\r\nALL BOOKS:");
foreach (var book in bookStore.Books)
{
    Console.WriteLine(book.name);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: No you did not understand me. How do I loop through members Prism and Paragraphia lists without directly accessing them like you showed. I have more then 2 of them and you suggest that for each and everyone I should bookstore.Prism  bookstore.Litreture bookstore.AnotherOne

Comment: Ok, that's indeed another question. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @padolebala: Does this help you out?