# How to foreach through a list of datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a list of 2 DataTables. I want to iterate through each of them, one at a time. How do I do this? There are 0 examples of going through a list of DataTables.

```
List<DataTable> test = new List<DataTable>();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in TEST.LIST)
{
    string value = dataRow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running");   //Looks for "Slave_IO_Running" status.

    if (value == "Yes")
    {
        results.Add(siteName + ": WORKING"); //adds working to the visual table 
    }
    else
    {
        results.Add(siteName + ": REPLICATION ERROR"); //adds not working to the result list
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: you'll need 2 for loops: `foreach (var testDataTable in test) { foreach (DataRow dataRow in testDataTable) {`

Comment: `foreach (var table in test)` ?  You'd loop through it like you'd loop through any collection.  Inside that loop you'd have a `DataTable`, and can loop through its rows like any other collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I loop through a List<T> and grab each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863187/how-can-i-loop-through-a-listt-and-grab-each-item)

Comment: But you've already written a `foreach`..Surely it's not much of a leap to expand this to a slightly different list?

Comment: Your last 5 questions appear to be just asking this same question over and over with slightly different code....

Answer (score 1):

for each datatable you can use `DataTable.Rows` and for each row you can access the properties as `row["columnName"]` or traverse each column in the corresponding row
like

```
 foreach(DataTable table in tables)
 {
   foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
     foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like this, assuming both tables contain the same columns:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in test.SelectMany(dt => dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()))
{
    // your code using the rows
}
```

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: `Rows` is a `DataRowCollection`, not an `IEnumberable<DataRow>`. Replace `dt.Rows` with `dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()`.

Comment: Now you have fixed your code, you should explain it.