# How can I get properties from nested objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, nested, json.net

i am new in c# language and I have json data and convert into c# object but i want to get nested properties from Response model and comments and all data from Response class also i need data from response class using foreach loop

```
public class Response
{
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string updateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Reviewer
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string oneAccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string vin { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class ShopReview
{
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string compCode { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Reviewer reviewer { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

}

public class RootObject
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public ShopReview[] shopReviews { get; set; }
}
```

i try with this code

```
   if (review.Response != null)
  {
     foreach (var shopResponse in review.Response)
     {
     CarReviewReply tmpReply = new CarReviewReply();
      {
      Comments = shResponse.Comments,
      LastUpdated = shopResponse.UpdateDate,
      ResponseDate = shopResponse.CreateDate,
      Status = shopResponse.Status
      };
  }
}
```

I got error "Does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: Are you looking for [How can I loop through a `List<T>` and grab each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18863187)?  That question is for `List<T>` but the answer applies to any collection, including arrays.

Comment: i try with loop foreach (var review in api.ShopReviews) { review.comments } but i need nested one from vehicle something  review.vehicle.model

Comment: Did you try `review.vehicle.model`? Why is that not a sufficient answer?

Comment: i got null value ..

Comment: Why are you doing `foreach` on the `Response` instead of on the `shopReviews` variable itself? Each `ShopReview` has only a single `Response`, but you have a whole array of `ShopReview`s.

Comment: because i already create one loop for shopreview array that store in "review" variable   but review inside other array that i need called response  :: foreach (var review in carReviewsApiResponse.ShopReviews)  inside other loop

Comment: This code shouldn't compile, why do you use the class name to access a property? Is this a typo?

Comment: now its working thnx guys