# How to loop thru a Generic Class / List

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I'm learning Generics thru MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)
and I want to do a foreach loop to display data in a console.writeline.

I tried to do the foreach loop as below but it's not working.

```
// Declare the generic class.
public class GenericList<T>
{
    public void Add(T input) { }
}
class TestGenericList
{
    private class ExampleClass { }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a list of type int.
        GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();
        list1.Add(150);

        // Declare a list of type string.
        GenericList<string> list2 = new GenericList<string>();
        list2.Add("Toyota");

        // Declare a list of type ExampleClass.
        GenericList<ExampleClass> list3 = new GenericList<ExampleClass>();
        list3.Add(new ExampleClass());
    }
}



        foreach (GenericList<T> item in list2.ToString().ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);   // NOT WORKING !!!!
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I loop through a List<T> and grab each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863187/how-can-i-loop-through-a-listt-and-grab-each-item)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by calling the method `ToString()` on `list2`, you will get the name of type of your object, because you didn't create your own implementation of method `ToString()`. So, you are trying to enumerate through letters of string "AppName.GenericList". Unfortunately, letters are of type 'char' and not GenericList.

Secondly, there is no backend behind method `Add` - items you are 'adding' to your list, in reality aren't added anywhere. Method `public void Add(T input) { }` does nothing (you should fill the brackets). GenericList at this stage stores no data.

Thirdly, you can't enumerate through your GenericList, because you didn't implement the method `GetEnumerator`. Only then you will be able to use keyword `foreach` on objects of your type.

Many of this issues will be solved by the end of the tutorial from link that you provided.