# How am I print out the query.List()

Tags: nhibernate

How am I print out the query.List()?
When I try to use Console.WriteLine(results) to get list.
It shows me like System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LocationSpecies.Domain.Location]
Am I going the right way?

```
  using (ISession session = SessionHelper.OpenSession())
                    using (ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        Location location = session.Get<Location>(19596);
    
                        double elevation = location.Elevation;
    
                        Console.WriteLine(elevation);
                       // String hql = "From LocationSpecies.Domain.Location E where E.LocationId like '1%'";
                        var query = session.QueryOver<Location>()
                            .Where(r => r.Name == "Australia");
                        var results = query.List();
                        trans.Commit();
                        session.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(results);
    
                    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I loop through a List<T> and grab each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863187/how-can-i-loop-through-a-listt-and-grab-each-item)

Answer (score 0):

above query will return list() object.
So you can get the object by using foreach loop like follows

```
enter code here   foreach(Location l : results){Console.writeline(l);}
```